# uitableview cell selection style

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

this weird thing is happening with my uitableview cell selection style, Instead of changing the color of the cell on selection its making the label in the cell disappear. I have no idea how to fix it.

this is the code I am using inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
cellActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Comment: shouldn't the selection style be defined in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *cellActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[cellActivityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(20, 20)];
[cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[cell addSubview:cellActivityIndicator];
```

where, here `[cellActivityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(20, 20)];` you enter position indicator in cell.

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

`[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];`

Comment: He wants the activity indicator to appear when the user has selected a certain cell, not before it is selected.